# Getting files of a particular file type with android Mediastore.File

Tags: android, mediastore

How do I use `Mediastore.Files` to get all the files of a particular file type,such as pdf files,present in both external and SD card storage.
I've just tried using the java `File` API but this takes long to list them.

Comment: You mean file extension?

Comment: @blackapps: Yes

Answer (score 0):

try this for only pdf file

```
private void showFileChooser() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    intent.setType("application/pdf");
    intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);

    try {
        startActivityForResult(
                Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select txt file"),
                0);
    } catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException ex) {
        // Potentially direct the user to the Market with a Dialog

    }
}
```